# Error in PHP data post to Python

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, post, urllib2

This is my PHP:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['one'];
echo $_POST['two'];
?>
```

This is my Python:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
mydata = [('one','1'),('two','2')]
mydata = urllib.urlencode(mydata)
path = 'http://example.com/example.gwt/war/my_php.php'
req = urllib2.Request(path, mydata)
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print page
```

This is my error:

> urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

What is this mean?
Any idea please, why does this happen?

Comment: where do you define `$_POST['one']`?

Comment: 503 means your server is unreachable. I dont think there's a problem with your code. (Apart from the fact that urlencode takes a dict rather a list of tuples.

Comment: i define it in my_php.php

Comment: When I navigate to `http://pglvm2009-v05.png.intel.com/webexec.gwt/war/get_schedules_run.php` from a browser, it gives me "Server not found". When I use Fiddler to sniff the network, I get error 502, saying "DNS Lookup for "pglvm2009-v05.png.intel.com" failed. The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found". Are you certain that this is a valid URL?

Comment: yes, of course you can't see it because the server use for internal only. i already change example url.